# How to get dynamic predicate using expressions when joining in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I wrote a static method which will give appropriate predicate lambda using expression api for different type of fields.

```
static Func<T, bool> Process<T>(string type)
{

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression predicate = Expression.Constant(true);
    if (type == "Start")
    {
        Expression prop = Expression.Property(parameter, type);
        Expression filter = Expression.LessThan(prop, Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now));
        predicate = Expression.AndAlso(predicate, filter);
    }
    //TODO: more if statments to come
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, parameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

The above code works fine if I do a single query operation in linq like this:

```
var del = Process<MyClass>("Start");
var data = DbContext.MyClass.Where(del); //gets the result data

public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I do a join on the MyClass entity

```
var data = DbContext.MyClass
         .Join(DbContext.Detail, mc => mc.Id, detail => detail.Id, (m, d) =>
                     new { m = m, d = d})
         .Where(del);
```

The above lines are giving compile time error

```
Error   CS1929  'IQueryable<<anonymous type: MyClass m, Detail d>>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Where<MyClass>(EnumerableRowCollection<MyClass>, Func<MyClass, bool>)' requires a receiver of type 'EnumerableRowCollection<MyClass>'
```

I understand that `.Where()` now expects an anonymous type which has **m** and **d** but not sure how to resolve this.

I'm pretty new to Expression API. Not sure how to achieve.

I've tried to achieve that by creating anonymous type variable, but that is a variable and not the type itself to pass it to `Process<T>()`.

Comment: In the Expression you are comparing `MyClass` to the `DateTime`, that's not a valid `Func<T,bool>`, you can only compare related / correct types, here you have to use the property of MyClass for building Func like Start / End which are DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your `Process` method is a `Where` clause for objects of type `MyClass`, so you can't use it to filter anonymous objects `{ m, d }`. Instead filter before the `Join`:

```
var data = DbContext.MyClass.Where(del);                        
                            .Join(DbContext.Detail,
                                  mc => mc.Id,
                                  detail => detail.Id,
                                  (m, d) => new { m, d }
                             );
```

Comment: Also change `Func<T, bool>` to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and `return lambda.Compile();` to `return lambda;`. Otherwise all your efforts will be for nothing, because the query will execute in memory after retrieving the whole `MyClass` table.